# How do you find the sum of a set of fractions where the denominator is increasing linearly?

Tags: limits, fractions

Is there a quick way to find the sum of fractions where the denominator increases linearly within a finite range and infinitely?

For example:

1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7 .....

or:

1/5 + 1/7 + 1/9 .... 1/101

Comment: Short answer: no. The finite sums do not  have a nice form. The infinite sums will diverge. Look up _harmonic series_.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Let $~\displaystyle s(n) ~\text{denote}~ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.$  Then, elementary Calculus gives that for $n \geq 3:$ $$s(n) - 1 < \log(n) < s(n) - \frac{1}{n}.$$  Here, $~\log(n)$ refers to the *natural logarithm* of $~n.$

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick way.

This is a generalization of a sub segment of the harmonic series, and while that can be estimated asymptotically, it cannot be computed exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an integral representation

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{An+B}=\int_0^1\frac{x^{AN+B}-x^{B}}{x(x^{A}-1)}dx$$

Though this doesn't really help to compute the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can *approximate* the result using [Euler-MacLaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) summation formula
$$\sum_{n=a}^b f(n) = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx +\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} + \frac{1}{6}\frac{f'(b) - f'(a)}{2!} +\cdots $$

So, if
$$f(n)=\frac 1 {\alpha n +\beta}$$
$$\sum_{n=a}^b f(n) =\frac 1 \alpha \log \left(\frac{\alpha\,  b+\beta }{ \alpha \,a+\beta }\right)+ \left(\frac{1}{ \alpha\,a +\beta }+\frac{1}{\alpha \, b+\beta }\right)+\frac \alpha{12}\left(\frac{1}{(a \alpha +\beta )^2}-\frac{1}{(\alpha  b+\beta )^2}\right)+\cdots$$

For your second case where $\alpha=1$, $\beta=0$, $a=5$, $b=101$, the approximation will be
$$\log \left(\frac{101}{5}\right)+\frac{53}{505}+\frac{848}{255025}+\cdots=\color{red}{3.1139}58$$ to be compared to the exact value
$$\frac{877105921057330616800795116172051213424683}{281670315928038407744716588098661706369472}=\color{red}{3.113945}$$ which corresponds to a relative error of $0.0004$%.

And we can do better adding the next derivatives.